# iOS Swift French Accents in Xcode and Label

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

need some help. For some reason, my custom font is displaying accents weirdly in both Xcode UILabel (static label) or programatically? Any help?

Tested the fonts in Photoshop and all seems fine...

This is how it is rendering in Xcode and simulator:

[image]

Swift code I am using:

```
var attributedString = NSAttributedString()
        let encodedData = theString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF16StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!

        let attributedOptions = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType]

        do {
            attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil)
            return attributedString

        } catch _ {
            print("Cannot create attributed String")
        }
```

Comment: How are you choosing the font for your attributed string?

Comment: Where did you get the custom font?  Maybe it does not include special characters, a problem which I've had recently.

Comment: Hm designer sent the font – the special characters work in Photoshop though?

Comment: It might be too late, but I had the same issue and it was because the string I tried to render was copy / paste from a document and the encoding was broken. Try to just re-tape accented characters.